# Is there a way to add a customized QGroupBox to any widgets/layouts?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, qt5

I have created a QMainWindow and a customized QGroupBox by Qt Designer and compiled to .py file.

This is my widgets hierarchy: `QMainWindow -> QStackedWidget -> QScrollArea -> QVBoxLayout -> QGroupBox(es).`  
But when I tried to add the customized QGroupBox (class `Ui_deck`) I have created above to the QVBoxLayout (belongs to class `Ui_main`), it shows nothing. 
Here is my code:

```
#main.py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

from main_ui import Ui_main
from deck_name import Ui_deck 

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_main):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.scroll_widget)
    deck = Ui_deck()
    deck.setupUi(groupbox)
    self.scroll_layout.addWidget(groupbox)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Main()
    ui.setupUi(main)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
#main_ui.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'deck_name.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_main(object):
    def setupUi(self, main):
        main.setObjectName("main")
        main.resize(621, 522)
        main.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        main.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(main)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stacked.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 621, 501))
        self.stacked.setObjectName("stacked")
        self.home = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.home.setObjectName("home")
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.home)
        self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 621, 511))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scroll.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scroll.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scroll.setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:vertical{\n"
"    width: 5px;\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical{\n"
"    border:0;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);\n"
"    border-radius: 2px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar:up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar:down-arrow:vertical{\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: none;\n"
"    color: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {\n"
"      border: none;\n"
"      background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"      border: none;\n"
"      background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.scroll.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setObjectName("scroll")
        self.scroll_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scroll_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 619, 509))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scroll_widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scroll_widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scroll_widget.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    height: 100px;\n"
"}\n"
"QWidget#scroll_widget{\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.scroll_widget.setObjectName("scroll_widget")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scroll_widget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.scroll_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.scroll_layout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.scroll_layout.setObjectName("scroll_layout")
        self.buttons = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.scroll_widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.buttons.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.buttons.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttons.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        self.buttons.setFont(font)
        self.buttons.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox#buttons{\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"}")
        self.buttons.setTitle("")
        self.buttons.setObjectName("buttons")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.buttons)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 0, 591, 50))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.add_deck = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.buttons)
        self.add_deck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 129, 40))
        self.add_deck.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.add_deck.setFont(font)
        self.add_deck.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#add_deck{\n"
"    border: 0;\n"
"    border-radius: 20px;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(132, 255, 16)\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#add_deck:hover{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(125, 234, 0)\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.add_deck.setObjectName("add_deck")
        self.scroll_layout.addWidget(self.buttons)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.scroll_layout)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.home)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.page_2)
        main.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(main)
        self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(main)

    def retranslateUi(self, main):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        main.setWindowTitle(_translate("main", "Flashcards"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("main", "All decks"))
        self.add_deck.setText(_translate("main", "Add deck"))
```

```
#deck_name.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'deck_name.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_deck(object):
    def setupUi(self, deck):
        deck.setObjectName("deck")
        deck.resize(565, 200)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(deck.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        deck.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        deck.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 200))
        deck.setWindowTitle("")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(deck)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 561, 201))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.deck_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.deck_name.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.deck_name.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.deck_name.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.deck_name.setFont(font)
        self.deck_name.setObjectName("deck_name")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.deck_name, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.button.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.button.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        self.button.setFont(font)
        self.button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"    border-radius: 12px;\n"
"}")
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.button)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.review = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.button)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.review.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.review.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.review.setFont(font)
        self.review.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#review{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(132, 255, 16);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#review:hover{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(125, 234, 0)\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.review.setObjectName("review")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.review)
        self.flash = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.button)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.flash.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.flash.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.flash.setFont(font)
        self.flash.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#flash{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(132, 255, 16);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#flash:hover{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(125, 234, 0)\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.flash.setObjectName("flash")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.flash)
        self.word_list = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.button)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.word_list.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.word_list.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.word_list.setFont(font)
        self.word_list.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#word_list{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(132, 255, 16);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#word_list:hover{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(125, 234, 0)\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.word_list.setObjectName("word_list")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.word_list)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.dropdown = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.dropdown.setFont(font)
        self.dropdown.setStyleSheet("border: none")
        self.dropdown.setObjectName("dropdown")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dropdown, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(deck)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(deck)

    def retranslateUi(self, deck):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.deck_name.setText(_translate("deck", "Deck_name"))
        self.review.setText(_translate("deck", "Review"))
        self.flash.setText(_translate("deck", "Flashcards mode"))
        self.word_list.setText(_translate("deck", "Word list mode"))
        self.dropdown.setText(_translate("deck", "..."))
```

Here is the output: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAtbH72oS9NdBzeEOMhW77ZXYZTBMycg/view?usp=sharing 
It is supposed to have two groupboxes in the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing an instance of `QtWidgets.QMainWindow` instead of `Main`. Try changing the last part of `main.py` to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```